# How to update from 15.10 to 16.04 without losing the data?

Tags: updates

I want to update from 15.10 to 16.04 . I am new to ubuntu so please i need your help . Also , i don't want to lose my data .

Answer (score 0):

With any upgrade, there's always a (very minimal) chance of data loss. With that being said, it is really easy to upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04, and there's no reason you'd be likely to lose any data in the process.

You don't even need to enter a terminal. Just open the "Software Updater" program. There should be a button that says "Upgrade..." Just hit that button and wait for about 20 minutes.

*Troubleshooting*: If the upgrade button isn't there, make sure you have all available updates installed and restart software updater. Make sure you're connected to the internet. In the update preferences dialog, make sure you check "Notify my about all new versions".